# ADO recordset PageCount property returns -1

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

ADO recordset PageCount property returns "-1"

```
CONST PAGESIZE = 10
Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open xSQL, Con1, 3, 3
RS.PageSize = PAGESIZE
```

If i try

```
response.write RS.PageCount
```

it returns -1

This was working a second ago, with a SQL

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
```

after i changed it to

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, field3 FROM table
```

the PageCount stopped working.

I've tried to change my query to

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, field3 FROM table) aa
```

with no success.

I can't figure out why this is happening, please give me a hand.

Comment: This has somethign to do with my recordset (cursor) type. In the RS.Open line has 3,3 (two times) i remove one, and is now working.

Comment: Apologies, this isn't a duplicate as it's talking about `PageCount` not `RecordCount` should open my eyes more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has somethign to do with my recordset (cursor) type. In the RS.Open line has 3,3 (two times) i remove one, and is now working.

```
CONST PAGESIZE = 10
Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open xSQL, Con1, 3
RS.PageSize = PAGESIZE
```